# need to format currency for TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, converters, currency

i parse a json object and suppose i have this value `1515.2777777777778` i need to parse the currency in this way:
`€ 1'515,27`

Is there a special class that can directly do the conversion? or should i do it in this way:

```
Double number = Double.valueOf(obj.getString("price"));
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("€ #\\'###.00");
String prezzo = decimalFormat.format(number);
```

but even in this way i t doesnt lieke the single apostrophe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format you need is `€ #,###.00`, `,` means you use a grouping separator.

Then, you need a `DecimalFormatSymbols` to specify the grouping symbol and the decimal symbol:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setGroupingSeparator('\'');
symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');

DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("€ #,###.00", symbols);
String prezzo = decimalFormat.format(number);
```

Result `€ 1'515,28`

Comment: This will return "$ .00" if the number is 0

Answer (score 8):

You can use `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()` or `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale locale)` to get the `NumberFormat` instance that can be used to format currencty values.